# Local scopes in Laravel Model didn't work

Tags: php, laravel, model, scope

I created new scope in Laravel's model and it didn't work at all. It seems invisible for the controller.

File test.php in Models:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Test extends Model
{
    public function scopeLatest(Builder $query, int $limit)
    {
        return $query
        ->select(['id', 'title', 'main_photo', 'area', 'price', 'city', 'short_desc'])
        ->whereIn('status', ['Dostepne', 'Zarezerwowane'])
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->limit($limit)
        ;
    }
}
```

Controller file:

```
$flats = Test::latest(3)->get();
```

In the end, I'm reciving every record in database. When I delete *get* methode in controller, i'm recive no records. Whatever I write in *scopeLatest* it doesn't matter.

Comment: are you sure you're showing the same scope you are using ? because that scope doesnt take a parameter for the limit while when you're using it you are sending `3` as a parameter. what are you getting with just `Flat::latest()->get();`

Comment: Yes, that's he same scope - it's just mistake during coping - I changed it.

With ```Flat::latest()->get();``` i get all records.

Comment: And the model is actually "Flat" not "Test", right?

Comment: Yes, yes, sorry - another mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a method named `latest` that exists on the Eloquent Query Builder; it is a public method so that is what you are calling directly. To be able to apply a scope (call a scope on the Builder) you would have to be calling a non existing or inaccessible (not visible) method which would make PHP call the `__call` method which would eventually be checking if a scope exists and then calling it.

Name your scope something else if you want to be able to apply it in the fluent fashion.

Comment: That's it, thanks a lot!